# Teamviewer in notification area only

Tags: notification-area

I was wondering if there was a simple way to close Teamviewer to the notification area like I would close Skype?

**EDIT:**

Just to clarify my initial post, I want to enable Teamviewer in the notification area so that I can close it in my open programs bar (click on x), and it would still be running in the notification area (Skype does that, I can option Banshee and Rhythmbox to do that, and Transmission does this too). All Tray puts it into the notification area, but the x still closes Teamviewer completely, and I have not found an optional setting in Teamviewer either.

Thanks for the answer though Karni! ;)

Comment: It'll probably not be exactly what you want if I understand correctly, but have you seen http://askubuntu.com/q/20989/9656 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's an application-specific behavior - you'd need to get the app makers to change it. However, moving it to another desktop will also cause it not to be an eyesore, while alltray as Karni suggested would fill the tray part.

Comment: Thanks Vadi, this has been my easyfix for a while now, I'll stick to it and whenever possible, suggest this feature to the app makers ;). Have a nice weekend!

Answer (score 6):

Sure, you can use alltray for that :)

Look it up in Applications -> Ubuntu Software Center, or use this command:

```
sudo apt-get install alltray
```

EDIT
To minimize the program, run alltray and point to the Window of it. It will hide in the tray. To hide/unhide to/from Tray, click the Tray icon of the program :)

Comment: I have tried that, over Teamviewer, and have now lost the connection ;) - not a big issue though. I will try again at home, but it might not have worked for me... I mean, I sudo'ed it, ran the program from accessories, clicked on the teamviewer window, it showed an icon in the area, and I then clicked the close icon on Teamviewer... that was the plan right? ;) Thanks for the quick response!

Comment: Hey pal! Sorry I didn't look back on askubuntu. No, if you close the Window, you close the program [because hiding to tray is implemented by external program Alltray, instead of TV itself].

Thus, what you should do, is:
- run Alltray
- point to Team Viewer window
- next time you want to hide to tray, click the Team Viewer icon in tray :)

Answer (score 2):

The option you might be looking for is called "Close to tray menu" and is available in Teamviewer's settings:

**Extras > Options > Advanced > "Show advanced options" > "Close to tray menu" check box.**

Check this box to have Teamviewer 'minimize' to the notification area, after clicking the X (exit button).

Hope this helps :)

**EDIT**:
If the "Close to tray menu" is grayed out, try the [following solution](http://teamviewerforums.com/index.php?topic=2462.0):

The reason the "Close To tray Menu" is grayed out is because you have "Start teamviewer with windows". It's like a failsafe. Assuming you want Teamviewer to start everytime windows starts, then that means you never want it closed, therefore it greys out the Close To Tray.
All you have to do is change the setting for startup.

Answer (score 0):

I only have a license for Teamviewer 7. I therefore don't know if this solution applies to other versions. If you go to **Extras > Options > Advanced** on the pc you wish to control you can deactivate the ability to (especially by accident) close Teamviewer.

This works equally on Windows or Linux.