# Is there a way to avoid Skype and Pidgin windows to show up at startup

Tags: startup, skype, window, pidgin

I have both Skype and Pidgin set up to automatically launch and sign in at startup and I do want that.

However, what I hate is that every time I boot or reboot, both window show up open and I have to manually close them. I just want the two programs to launch silently and only show up as tray icons, without opening their windows every time at startup.

I can't seem to find any such option in either of them.

Comment: use this

http://askubuntu.com/questions/20989/how-do-i-tell-a-start-up-program-to-start-minimized

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Skype has an option to start minimized, which can be reached by clicking on your options menu and activate the appropriate checkbox as shown here:

[image]

Pidgin is working in a different behaviour and no "start minimized" checkbox somewhere, insted you can define the opening behavior by closing pidgin in the desired way, it means: close pidgin while minimized to tray and it will open the same way it was when closed. The same when closing with the contacts list open as mentioned here: http://developer.pidgin.im/ticket/1888

[image]

Quoted for your convenience:

## Change History

Changed 5 years ago by nosnilmot  pending changed from 0 to 1

> Pidgin will start minimized to tray if it was minimized to tray when
>   it was last exited. Isn't this sufficient?

Anyway, if that's no sufficient for you, you can dive into coding and use tricks like this:

> Pidgin does not have an option that allows a user decide whether the
>   Pidgin buddy list window starts minimized or not. It just remembers
>   the state of the window when it quits, and restores the last window
>   state.
>
> The last window status is stored in $HOME/.purple/prefs.xml:

```
...
<pref name='pidgin'>
  ...
  <pref name='blist'>
  ...
    <pref name='list_visible' type='bool' value='0'/> <!-- 0: invisible, 1: visible -->
    <pref name='list_maximized' type='bool' value='0'/> <!-- 0: normal, 1: maximized -->
  ,,,
  </pref>
</pref>
...
```

> When the list_visible property is set to 0, you will see Pidgin minimizes its
>   buddy list window into the system tray (or the notification area). How
>   can we make sure it’s always set to 0 when Pidgin updates it when it
>   exits? Let’s write a shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash
perl -pi -e "s/pref name='(list_visible|list_maximized)' type='bool' value='[1-9]'/pref name='\$1' type='bool' value='0'/gi" ~/.purple/prefs.xml
/usr/bin/pidgin &
```

> The first perl command searches
>   the list_visible and list_maximized properties and replaces their
>   values with 0 before Pidgin starts. Problem solved!
>
> Not that I like this workaround. I still just can’t believe there is
>   no option about this.

*Source:* http://planet.jboss.org/post/how_to_start_pidgin_minimized_or_always_start_pidgin_with_its_buddy_list_invisible

Using **Plugins** is also valid, like the "***Buddy List Options 2.6.3***" (normally installed in the plugin package), which features the "Hide the buddy list when it is created",

[image]

The same as "***Extended preferences 0.7***", featuring the "Hide buddy list at startup" among other useful options. Extended Preferences 0.7 can be easily installed via `"sudo apt-get install pidgin-extprefs"` in a terminal.

[image]

Fortunately this is about Linux, almost everything can be achieved :) so...

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks a lot. How could I miss Skype's option :$
Regarding pidgin, in my case (and it seems in ubuntu in general because of a bug) it does _not_ remember its closed status. It always shut down my system with pidgin's window closed, but it always pops up at startup. However thanks to the information you provided I guess I'll be able to manually edit the xml. Thank you

Comment: sorry I can't vote this up, not enough reputation

Answer (score 0):

While some windows management rules can be configured inside CCSM there are few that still does not exist there. One of them is minimizing a window of an application that was just launched.

To fill this gap there is a nice additional tool that can execute those kind of rules. It is called *Devilspie (Devil's Pie)* and has two parts: rule engine and graphical rules editor.

Install both by executing `sudo apt-get install devilspie gdevilspie`.
Once installed, just launch `gdevilspie` and create two new rules that will minimize both Skype and Pidgin windows.