# How can I start a script in a minimised Gnome Terminal?

Tags: command-line, launcher, gnome-terminal, minimize, nohup

I can start a command in a new Gnome Terminal as follows:

```
nohup gnome-terminal --window-with-profile=Background --command ls >/dev/null 2>&1&
```

(Based on https://askubuntu.com/a/46630/7146 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/10708326/236081)

However, I want the new terminal window to start minimised in the Launcher. How can I do that?

Comment: Purely out of curiosity, have you considered alternatives like terminator or tilda?

Comment: @muru I'll have a look, especially if they have a start minimised option :)

Comment: drop down terminals like tilda and guake usually have that option. Terminator has pretty much any option I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I based my solution on some of the answers given for [minimising](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20989) and [maximising](https://askubuntu.com/a/27833/7146) windows. In this case, though, I wanted to target just this Gnome Terminal (but not other Gnome Terminals), so I gave it a name using `--title`:

```
nohup gnome-terminal --title="Tiny Terminal" --window-with-profile=Background --command "$argv" >/dev/null 2>&1&
```

And created a Devil's Pie rule for windows named "Tiny Terminal":

```
(if
(is (window_name) "Tiny Terminal")
(begin (minimize) )
)
```

(If you prefer, you can use gdevilspie to create this rule in a GUI.)

This achieves the original desired affect. However, when I tried it out, I realised that I also wanted the terminal to restore to a maximised state, [which is addressed in a separate answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/490694).

Answer (score 4):

What about minimizing your window after creating it?

```
$ (mate-terminal --window-with-profile=Background --title=xxx  --command top >/dev/null 2>&1 &); sleep 0.1; xdotool windowminimize $(xdotool search --name xxx|head -1)
```

I use Mate instead of Gnome but it should work just the same if you replace `mate-terminal` with `gnome-terminal`:

```
$ (gnome-terminal --window-with-profile=Background --title=xxx  --command top >/dev/null 2>&1&); sleep 0.1; xdotool windowminimize $(xdotool search --name xxx|head -1)
```

First, i create new window with `mate-terminal` and I assign name using `--title=xxx` option. After that I use `xdotool search --name xxx|head -1` to find id of this window and I pass it to `xdotool windowminimize`. `sleep 0.1` delay is necessary because window needs a little while to be created.

Instead of using window title you can also use other search options:

```
$ xdotool search Usage: xdotool search [options] regexp_pattern
--class         check regexp_pattern agains the window class
--classname     check regexp_pattern agains the window classname
--maxdepth N    set search depth to N. Default is infinite.
                -1 also means infinite.
--onlyvisible   matches only windows currently visible
--pid PID       only show windows belonging to specific process
                Not supported by all X11 applications
--screen N      only search a specific screen. Default is all screens
--desktop N     only search a specific desktop number
--limit N       break search after N results
--name          check regexp_pattern agains the window name
--title         DEPRECATED. Same as --name.
--all           Require all conditions match a window. Default is --any
--any           Windows matching any condition will be reported
--sync          Wait until a search result is found.
-h, --help      show this help output

If none of --name, --classname, or --class are specified, the  defaults are: --name --classname --class
```

Example using `--class 'mate-terminal'` option:

```
(mate-terminal --command 'top' &) && sleep 0.1 && xdotool windowminimize $(xdotool search --class 'mate-terminal' |sort|tail -1)
```

This should work for gnome:

```
(gnome-terminal --command 'top' &) && sleep 0.1 && xdotool windowminimize $(xdotool search --class 'gnome-terminal' |sort|tail -1)
```

I sort output of `xdotool search` since newly created window should be last one listed.

Comment: Worked most time also for me (tested with `gnome-terminal --title=123 & disown && sleep 1 && xdotool windowminimize $(xdotool search --name 123|head -1)`), but the gnome title will be renamed automatically through the `$HOME.bashrc` a few seconds after startup, so the time window is really short and sometimes it fails for me.

Comment: @Tuknutx, I updatet my answer.

Comment: It works really good for me with `sleep 0.8`.

Answer (score 3):

Gnome-Terminal has no option to start minimised.

The following is more a workaround to do this:

First `wmctrl` is needed, but **not the version from the repositories because this version doesn't have an option tho minimize windows**. (If you have already installed `wmctrl` you have to remove it).

Download the version from github https://github.com/geekless/wmctrl/archive/master.zip and install it (follow the INSTALL file -> `./configure` then `sudo make install`). If you get `error: X11/Xmu/WinUtil.h` you have also to install `sudo apt-get install libxmu-dev` and then try again.

Then you can run from commandline this for example:

```bsh
gnome-terminal -x sh -c "ls; bash" & disown && sleep 3 &&  wmctrl -i -Y  $(wmctrl -l | awk -F' ' 'END{print $1}')
```

Explanation:

1. `gnome-terminal -x sh -c "ls; bash" & disown` run gnome-terminal in background and execute a command (in this case `ls`)
2. `sleep 3` wait until the gnome-terminal window appears (you can experiment with this value, 3 seconds could be to short or to long, depends on your hardware)
3. `wmctrl -i -Y`  -i ->  Interpret  window  arguments as a numeric value, -Y -> Iconify (minimize) the window
4. `$(wmctrl -l | awk -F' ' 'END{print $1}')` or `$(wmctrl -l | tail -1 | cut -d' ' -f1)` get the window id of the last opened window (should be the window id of gnome-terminal in this case)

---

To simplify it you can add a function to your `$HOME/.bashrc` file:

```bsh
gterm-min() {
    gnome-terminal -x sh -c "$1; bash" & disown  
    sleep 3   
    wmctrl -i -Y  $(wmctrl -l | awk -F' ' 'END{print $1}')
}
```

then you could use it like this:

```
gterm-min "ls -la"
```

Comment: `wmctrl -l | awk -F' ' 'END{ print $1}'` enough. You don't need two pipes.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I launch "The Language Tool" server, without sleep, witout loop:

```
#!/bin/bash

LT_WIN_NAME='The Language Tool'

xterm -geometry 126x12+0+0 -T "${LT_WIN_NAME}" -e\
 java -cp languagetool-server.jar org.languagetool.server.HTTPServer --allow-origin "*" &
xdotool windowminimize $(xdotool search --sync --name "${LT_WIN_NAME}")
```