# Is there software to periodically start and close an application?

Tags: command-line, software-recommendation, schedule

Exemplary use case:

I would like to start [Telegram Desktop](https://github.com/telegramdesktop/tdesktop) periodically every 3 hours for 15 minutes, to check for newly incoming messages. After 15 minutes, the application should close again and re-launch after the next 3 hours.

Comment: This would be extremely easy to script. Would starting the application do, to make it check? If so, what is the command to run it?

Comment: With `cron` you can clearly start programs. You could also cron  a `kill -15`, but it depends on the application whether it handles it as a gentle nudge to shut down, ignores it or just crashes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### Cron versus background script

Of course the very first thing that pops into the mind is to use `cron`. Whether you use cron, or a small background script is mainly a matter of taste.

The advantage of cron is that it hooks up on an existing process (although a script adds, well, actually *nothing* to the processor load).

The advantage of a background script is that is more flexible; simply kill it and run it with other arguments if you'd like to change time- or other settings. You can also re- use it with other applications without having to do another setup, just a command is enough.

The script below can be run by the command (e.g.)

```
python3 <script> <command_to_run_application> <cycle_time> <application_run_time> force
```

Where the last argument, if set, *forcefully* kills the application. If not set, the application will close gracefully, to make sure possible changes etc. will not be lost.

#### The script

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess
import time
import sys

force = False
args = sys.argv[1:]; app = args[0].replace("'", "")
proc = app.split()[0].split("/")[-1]
cycle = int(args[1])*60; run = int(args[2])*60

try:
    if args[3] == "force":
        force = True
except IndexError:
    pass

def get_pid(proc_name):
    try:
        return subprocess.check_output(
            ["pgrep", proc_name]
            ).decode("utf-8").strip()
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
        pass

def kill(pid, force):
    if force == False:
        subprocess.Popen(["kill", "-s", "TERM", pid])
    elif force == True:
        subprocess.Popen(["kill", pid])

while True:
    subprocess.Popen(["/bin/bash", "-c", app])
    time.sleep(run)
    pid = get_pid(proc)
    if pid != None:
        kill(pid, force)
    time.sleep(cycle - run)
```

#### To use

- Copy the script into an empty file, save it as `cycle_run.py`
- Run it with the command:

  ```
  python3 /path/to/cycle_run.py <command> <cycle_time> <application_run_time> force
  ```

  where:

  - `<command>` is the command to run the application (without the `--%u` -section, in my case, copied from the `.desktop` file: `/home/jacob/Downloads/Telegram/Telegram`)
  - `<cycle_time>` is the (total) cycle time in minutes (3 hours = 180 in your example)
  - `<application_run_time>` is the time the application should run in minutes (15 in your example)
  - `force` is an optional argument, to *forcefully* kill the application. Simply leave it away to *gracefully* kill the application.

#### Running applications with arguments

If you run an application with arguments, make sure you use quotes *around the command to run the application*, e.g.:

```
python3 /path/to/cycle_run.py 'gedit /home/jacob/Desktop/test.sh' 30 5
```

#### Running applications minimized or in tray

Starting and terminating applications periodically will often be needed only minimized and/or in tray. As requested by OP, a few remarks on that:

- *If* an application offers starting up in tray from command line, simply use the argument to do so. In the case of `Telgram`, the argument to use is:

  ```
  -startintray
  ```

  although the option seems not to work on all systems (it does on mine), as mentioned [here](https://github.com/telegramdesktop/tdesktop/issues/407). You will have to test in your situation.
- If the application does not offer the command line option to startup minimized or in tray, I'd suggest using the (this) script in combination with [the one here](https://askubuntu.com/a/663288/72216) (I'd suggest the `pid`- version), which will make it possible to startup the application minimized.

Comment: Dear @JacobVlijm, you have an amazing skillset! Thank you very much for this Christmas present. Your script works great. Same as "Take a Break", I could imagine this script to turn into a nice, simply GUI where the user can define the application(s), the cycle time and the application run time. This GUI could then run at startup to prepare applications such as Telegram or Skype. What do you think?

Comment: @orschiro sounds perfect! The gui is almost ready to use, with a few changes :). Have a nice Christmas!

Comment: would it be possible to force applications to open minimised or in background?

Comment: @orschiro off course, what do you have in mind?

Comment: For example, launching Telegram with your script opens the application in the foreground. This is very annoying when you're working on something else. It would be great if your script could provide an option for Telegram to start its main window in the background or simply minimised with its tray icon.

Comment: Hi @orschiro added a section to the answer.

Comment: this is fantastic. Thanks again for your perfectly suited solution! :)

Answer (score 5):

1. Edit your cron with `crontab -e`
   and add this line into your crontab to run it as schedule job for every 3 hours

   ```
   00 */3 * * * * ~/killtelegram.sh >/dev/null 2>&1
   ```

2.Open your terminal and type below command

```
touch ~/killtelegram.sh
chmod +x ~/killtelegram.sh
```

open killtelegram.sh with your favorate editor and write as below

```
#!/bin/bash
telegram &
sleep 15m
pkill telegram
```

Save and exit

thats it. It will open automatically for every 3 Hours and it will stay for 15 min and It will get killed.

Comment: Hi Raja, would you consider voting on this: http://askubuntu.com/tags/schedule/synonyms ?