# How do I get Skype for Linux alpha minimized to system tray at autostart

Tags: 16.04, skype, autostart, minimize

I am fairly new to Ubuntu and I installed Skype for Linux alpha yesterday in my Ubuntu 16.04 64-bit.

I added an [entry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lbVLx.png) in the startup applications using the command `skypeforlinux -silent`. Now, every time I start my system, skype windows opens maximized. I would like to know how to start it minimized to tray with system start.

Comment: Don't know if there is a built-in option for doing so. This is a related question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/663187/how-can-i-run-a-program-on-startup-minimized

Comment: The developers have now added a built in option to minimize skype on startup.

Comment: Good catch, rsnaveen. It seems to have been [added in version 1.15](https://community.skype.com/t5/Linux/What-s-New-in-Skype-1-15-for-Linux-Alpha/m-p/4566866). It would be good if you could post that as an answer to your question.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson The option has been added but it is not working! Shouldn't we wait until it actually works to add it as an answer?

Comment: Yeah, indeed we should. I didn't test it.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson 'Minimize to Tray' finally works now with version 5.0.0.5.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

'Minimize to tray on startup' functionality has been integrated in the app and is fully functional from version 5.0.0.5. The app however is Skype for Linux Beta at this point.

Comment: FTR: the setting is: `Tools → Settings → General → ✓ Launch Skype in the background`

Answer (score 1):

You can make a script which starts skype on startup, and which then closes it "gracefully" using `wmctrl -c`.
In my own scrypt I do something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
skypeforlinux &
wmctrl -c Skype ;  sleep 0.5
wmctrl -c Skype ;  sleep 0.5
wmctrl -c Skype ; 
etc...
```

I some cases, skype takes some time to open, that's why I use multiple delayed commands `wmctrl`.
Of course you have to make the script executable, using `chmod u+x [SCRIPT_FILE]`, and then add it to the startup list.
Also I use the nice program `devilspie` to rearrange all my windows at startup as I want.