# How can I start Hexchat minimized with the main window hidden?

Tags: irc, hexchat

I added [Hexchat IRC](https://hexchat.github.io/) client to my startup applications. After logging into my session, it shows the main window which I would like to automatically hide and minimize it to its tray icon.

Comment: Will this help: https://askubuntu.com/q/663187/57576 ?

Comment: Potentially. I also found [this](https://github.com/hexchat/hexchat/issues/1748).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hexchat can be launched to tray and skipping the main window with `hexchat --minimize=2`.