# run shorcut hidden in my ubuntu 16.04

Tags: virtualbox

i add to my startup manager of ubuntu 16.04 the following command.

```
/usr/lib/virtualbox/VirtualBox --comment "WINDOWS 7" --startvm "22591f38-3b08-4240-b2dc-b0f62714ee99"
```

But the question is can i make something to run the virtual machine with the startup hidden or minimized.

Comment: Do you want to keep the VM completely hidden – like a server? In that case, you can use [VBoxVmService](http://techgenix.com/start-virtualbox-service/).

Comment: i mean hide the window not the server.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there's a way, if you want to write a script. See the answer to a similar question on this site for an example from someone more knowledgeable than I:

[How can I run a program on startup, minimized?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/663187/how-can-i-run-a-program-on-startup-minimized)