# Alternative to using xdotool for Starting an application in hidden mode in ubuntu

Tags: 20.04, xdotool

I found this link to start an application in minimized/hidden mode : [How can I run a program on startup, minimized?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/663187/how-can-i-run-a-program-on-startup-minimized)

Here we are first launching our application and then using xdotool to minimize/hide the active visible window.

Is there any alternative solution available in linux to start the application in hidden mode similar to windows(which used WindowStyle-hidden for this purpose)?